# Openstack TripleO undercloud installation "could not find class ::ironic::drivers::deploy"

Tags: puppet, openstack, tripleo

My host is:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
```

The host setup was done as described here: http://docs.openstack.org/developer/tripleo-docs/environments/environments.html#virtual-environment up to the "Continue with Undercloud ..." step

The result:

```
sudo virsh list --all
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 3     baremetalbrbm_0                running
 4     instack                        running
 -     baremetalbrbm_1                shut off
```

The undercloud setup was done as described here: http://docs.openstack.org/developer/tripleo-docs/installation/installation.html

The installation was attempted on the instack VM. Did the SSL setup as well.

Running

```
openstack undercloud install
```

fails with

```
+ puppet apply --detailed-exitcodes /etc/puppet/manifests/puppet-stack-config.pp Notice: Scope(Class[Tripleo::Firewall::Post]): At this stage, all network traffic is blocked. Warning: Scope(Class[Swift]): swift_hash_suffix has been deprecated and should be replaced with swift_hash_path_suffix, this will be removed Warning: Scope(Class[Nova::Keystone::Auth]): Note that service_name parameter default value will be changed to "Compute Service" (according future release. In case you use different value, please update your manifests accordingly. Warning: Scope(Class[Nova::Keystone::Auth]): Note that service_name_v3 parameter default value will be changed to "Compute Service v3" (acco in a future release. In case you use different value, please update your manifests accordingly. Warning: Scope(Class[Glance::Api]): The known_stores parameter is deprecated, use stores instead Warning: Scope(Class[Glance::Api]): default_store not provided, it will be automatically set to glance.store.filesystem.Store Warning: Scope(Class[Nova::Api]): In N cycle, enabled_apis will have to be an array of APIs to enable. Warning: Scope(Class[Neutron::Server]): identity_uri, auth_tenant, auth_user, auth_password, auth_region configuration options are deprecateted options Warning: Scope(Class[Neutron::Agents::Dhcp]): The dhcp_domain parameter is deprecated and will be removed in future releases Warning: Scope(Class[Heat]): Default value for rabbit_heartbeat_timeout_threshold parameter is different from OpenStack project defaults Warning: Scope(Class[Heat]): "admin_user", "admin_password", "admin_tenant_name" configuration options are deprecated in favor of auth_plugi Warning: Scope(Class[Nova::Network::Neutron]): neutron_auth_plugin parameter is deprecated and will be removed in a future release, use neut Error: Could not find class ::ironic::drivers::deploy for instack on node instack Error: Could not find class ::ironic::drivers::deploy for instack on node instack
+ rc=1
+ set -e
+ echo 'puppet apply exited with exit code 1' puppet apply exited with exit code 1
+ '[' 1 '!=' 2 -a 1 '!=' 0 ']'
+ exit 1 [2016-05-19 15:32:29,361] (os-refresh-config) [ERROR] during configure phase. [Command '['dib-run-parts', '/usr/libexec/os-refresh-config/cot status 1]

[2016-05-19 15:32:29,362] (os-refresh-config) [ERROR] Aborting... Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instack_undercloud/undercloud.py", line 987, in install
    _run_orc(instack_env)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instack_undercloud/undercloud.py", line 866, in _run_orc
    _run_live_command(args, instack_env, 'os-refresh-config')   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instack_undercloud/undercloud.py", line 444, in _run_live_command
    raise RuntimeError('%s failed. See log for details.' % name) RuntimeError: os-refresh-config failed. See log for details. Command 'instack-install-undercloud' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Tried to install the ironic api as described here http://docs.openstack.org/developer/ironic/deploy/install-guide.html although to my understanding, this should not be necessary, since the undercloud was not installed on a baremetal machine.

Same result.

Answer (score 0):

Some hours of Puppet readings later, I went into the /etc/puppet/modules/ironic/manifests/drivers folder and found, to no surprise, that the deploy class was not there. Perhaps it should not have been needed? I copied it from https://github.com/openstack/puppet-ironic/blob/master/manifests/drivers/deploy.pp and it seems to have got past the error originally reported. Fingers crossed.